# Cannot Execute a .sh file by PHP

Tags: php, laravel-5, sh

I am trying to backup database through .sh file. Its working fine if I open the file manually. But I am trying to do it with PHP(laravel).

Here is my mysql_backup.sh file:

```
#!/bin/bash

#
#   Use this script to perform backups of one or more MySQL databases.
#

# Databases that you wish to be backed up by this script. You can have any number of databases specified; encapsilate each database name in single quotes and separate each database name by a space.
#
# Example:
# databases=( '__DATABASE_1__' '__DATABASE_2__' )
databases=('sasty')

# The host name of the MySQL database server; usually 'localhost'
db_host="127.0.0.1"

# The port number of the MySQL database server; usually '3306'
db_port="3306"

# The MySQL user to use when performing the database backup.
db_user="root"

# The password for the above MySQL user.
db_pass=""

# Directory to which backup files will be written. Should end with slash ("/").
backups_dir="C:/Users/Kapil/backup/"

backups_user=""

# Date/time included in the file names of the database backup files.
datetime=$(date +'%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S')

for db_name in ${databases[@]}; do
        # Create database backup and compress using gzip.
        C:/xampp/mysql/bin/mysqldump -u $db_user -h $db_host -P $db_port --password=$db_pass $db_name | gzip -9 > $backups_dir$db_name--$datetime.sql.gz
done

# Set appropriate file permissions/owner.
chown $backups_user:$backups_user $backups_dir*--$datetime.sql.gz
chmod 0400 $backups_dir*--$datetime.sql.gz
```

I am using PHP code for this

```
shell_exec('/path/to/my/file');
```

But its not working. however shell_exec('ls') is working fine. How to solve my problem?

Comment: What's the owner and permission of your `'/path/to/my/file'`?

Comment: It looks like you are attempting to execute the path directly.  Is the file (I assume a script), located at `/path/to/my/file` marked as executable?  Is it timing out?  What error messages do you see in your logs?  Does the user running the PHP script (e.g., `www-data`) have the permissions to execute that script?

Comment: `ls` on windows, that's new to me.

Comment: @AtaurRahman file permission is read & execute, read, write

Comment: @hunteke the file name is mysql_backup.sh . i did not get any error message. instead of using file I also tried with the codes . but no luck

Comment: @LawrenceCherone i am using vagrant on my machaine. but i want to use it xampp in windows

Comment: @KapilPaul And permissions of `mysql_backup.sh`?  Is it executable?  Does the Apache/PHP user have the correct permissions to execute it?  Try showing [all errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053424/how-do-i-get-php-errors-to-display).

Comment: @hunteke I execute this normally. I just open the file via git bash and its working. I don't know if the apache/php user have the correct permission for it. How to check the permissions?

Comment: You're running Apache/PHP on Windows, but are running the bash script through Git Bash.  As @LawrenceCherone noted, `ls` on Windows (*not* through Git Bash) is confusing.  My first thought is that you need to execute `sh` and _that_ needs to run the backup script.  Something like: `/path/to/sh /path/to/mysql_backup.sh`

Answer (score -1):

php.ini

disable_functions =exec,passthru,shell_exec,system,proc_open,popen,curl_exec,curl_multi_exec,parse_ini_file,show_source

remove shell_exec